# Restoring In-App purchases

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, game-center

I'm creating a game where the player can buy non-consumable items, there are 10 to buy and once bought they stay bought. The transactions for these items (a simple boolean for each item) is recorded on a server (Parse.com).

So I'm unsure what I need to do with my restore button as it doesn't matter what device the player signs into my game on, as long as they use the same account (which is tied to their GameCenter details) the game will know what items they have bought anyway, so there's no need for my game to have a restore button, but Apple says I need one, so what should I do?

Answer (score 3):

With non-consumable items ,you may not have a "restore button" but you must have a restore function. My app has no restore button , but has a restore function , and it also approved by apple. **But it is better to has a restore function for non-consumable items. And you must has a restore function**

And Why non-consumable items need restore ?

In my app , When user purchase my items and my local app has a transactions , At this time , the device maybe offline suddenly. So his payment success but purchasing failed , this situation should restore. And another situation ,  When user purchase my items and my local app has a transactions, I pass the transactions to my server . My server check the transactions with apple server , At this time , my server is down .So his payment success but purchasing failed , this situation also should restore.

Comment: Ok so basically a restore button, could just check to see if the items have already been purchased and if they have then set the correct values on the server, meaning then that I need to be able to check if the items have been purchased or not.

Comment: @Phil when you receive the transactions , you should save it , and pass it to your server , if your server has a "success" or a "not available" call back , you can delete the transactions. Or you should save the transactions for restore. When you click the restore , you should check the user whether has a saved transactions, if have , so pass the save transactions to your server

Comment: @Phil most iap function demo in github has the restore function

Comment: When the user makes a purchase, I record that on the server, but like you said there might be a situation where it never makes it to the server, if that is the case then I need to check what purchases the player has made with Apple, and then set the correct values on the server again, but I don't know how to check what purchases have been made with apple.

Comment: @Phil Apple not offer you to check what purchases have been made with apple for non-consumable items. When user pay , you can get a transactions from Apple , you should save the transactions in your local app , And delete it when user purchases success or faild( "not available"). If user want to restore , you should only check your save transactions.If there is no saved transactions , it means no need to restore.If there is a saved transactions you should only pass the saved transactions to your server

Comment: Your explanation in cases need to restore function help my mind clearly. Thanks so much.